# Use Composite or Hierarchical Entity? Improving utterance confidence

Tags: azure-language-understanding

Want to handle an utternace in the following format

"I met [a-PersonName] at [a-Business/VenueName] in [a-GeographicalLocation]"

Sample utterances might be

- I met Jane Allan at Starbucks in Bellevue
- I met james at Borders in New York
- I met Lily Tomlin at Disney in Orlando Florida

I believe I want to map the above to some of the existing built-in entities and/or domains

- [a-PersonName] -> builtin: personName
- [a-Business/VenueName] -> domain/Entity: Places.PlaceName
- [a-GeographicalLocation] -> builtin: Geography2

Results/problem: I get matched to none most of the time. Sometimes it matches my intent but it only matches PersonName and Geography but never all three

What I've tried but neither improved the results or matches NONE

- creating a composite entity
- creating a hierarchical entity

Q: Should this be a hierarchical entity? or Composite?